# Unable to move the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have set the things like on clicking on an image text appears and then again clicking it disappears but i am having number of images so now problem is it appears but goes into the another image

Comment: Add relevant code to your question.

Comment: Post your code or  generate http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You can fond the code 
http://180.211.110.195/design-projects/muktipatel/demo/Html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use Div tags to make placeholders for where you want the text to go.   That will push the images down once the text appears and readjusts when the text disappears.

If you like, give is an example of your HTML, CSS and JS or Jquery so we can give you an exact solution.

Comment: You can find the code here
http://180.211.110.195/design-projects/muktipatel/demo/Html/index.html

Comment: What do you want it do it when and image is clicked and the text appears?  For example do you want it to push the image next to it over and display the text?

Comment: On Click on image text appears and rest of the block moves right side.

Answer (score 0):

you should use different ids or classes for different images so that your action will be limited to that particular image .Provide more details about your question for a brief answer